# Are patches, updates, etc released at the same time worldwide?

Tags: ps4

I intend to buy a PS4 here in the US and use it in Iceland over the holidays. The PS4 will not be released in Iceland until January 29th. It has been confirmed that the PS4 is auto-voltage, so I am not worried about the hardware, and the games are not region based, so I am not worried about that either. I am worried about the software.

Since Sony does not intend to release its console until the end of January, do they block software updates, patches, etc. from ISP providers in the countries where the console has not been released yet?

Comment: Seems unlikely that you would be unable to get the patches/updates. Assuming you are able to connect to PSN without an issue (can't see why not), it sounds counter-intuitive that Sony would spend time placing blocks on crucial software updates for regions where the console is not yet available.  Posting as a comment because I don't have any sources/concrete examples, but I really wouldn't worry.

Comment: Thanks Turbo. I also would consider it odd for Sony to make an effort to block it in that manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can answer this yet. As there have only been one patch to the system (available worldwide). There is not enough data available to say anything general.